# Get the source path of an image element

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building a web application using ExtJS4 and I want to be able to get the source of an image element. I know I can use the line:

```
document.getElementById("imageID").getAttribute('src');
```

However, the issue I have with that solution is that the code is dependent on the `id` property. I won't be able to reuse this code if I have an class with a panel and an image inside since I will have conflicting ids if I duplicate the class. What I resorted to instead is to set an itemID in the image inside my panel.

Is there a way to get the image source using only the itemID property? Or do i really have to stick with my the id property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

Navigate to your image element and assign it to a variable then do:

```
imgSrc1 = img.getEl().getAttribute('src');
```

where img is your image variable